# dynamodb - how to efficiently get next free number

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a **node.js** application using **dynamodb** as database.

I have a Table where one attribute (not primary-key or sort-key) stores the used number of my application. Lets call it #a. #a contains number values which needs to be unique. On every new entry #a get mostly incremented by 1, if that incremented number does not exists. Now I need a way to get the next possible (free) number that can be used up for a new entry. lets say I'm currently at the value 99 and the table already contains all the value from 100 -  10.000, I need to get back 10.001.

I tried to keep track of the used number-values in a different table row, by storing them in a list, but I **rapidly exceeding the 400kb memory constraint** this method also includes an overhead when calculating the next free entry, which I want to avoid in my nodejs express app.

You guys know how to solve this ?

Comment: Is it possible to use GUID/UUID as a primary key, instead of a running number?

Comment: The primary key is already in use, I can use the sort key if you can tell me the purpose for that